# Nodejs PUT request with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, post, request

I'm trying to make a PUT request using request to a url:

```
    request({
            uri: 'http://apiurl.url/1.0/data?token=' + APItoken,
            method: 'PUT',
            data: [{
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    body: JSON.stringify(APIpostObj)
            }],
            json: true
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                    return console.error('upload failed:', error);
            }
            console.log('Server responded with:', body);
    })
```

I get the error:

```
 'Error number': 303, Error: 'Empty PUT on /data endpoint'
```

There are two parameters required: id (a number) and bdata (JSON). The APIpostObj would contain them as {"id":33, "bdata":{...}}.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Cristian did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 request({
        uri: 'http://apiurl.url/1.0/data?token=' + APItoken,
        method: 'PUT',
        json: [{
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                body: JSON.stringify(APIpostObj)
        }]
},
function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', error);
        }
        console.log('Server responded with:', body);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this. Usually works fine with me.

```
request({
    uri: url,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: APIpostObj,
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    // Do Stuff
})
```